# Gettier Problems and God

Tags: epistemology, theology, gettier

What to the Gettier Problems mean for God? Given my (limited) research, the Gettier Problems say if something is true (the T in JTB), one cannot always have knowledge that it is true. If God knows everything that is true, it seems that is impossible. Is this a sound argument?

Comment: I'm not really following your questions. The Gettier problems are problems for the idea that knowledge is justified true belief. If you think they succeed, there are other definitions of knowledge out there or you can bolster JTB. That they exist and critique JTB doesn't have any immediate relation to God. Instead, it just seems that omniscience would make it so that Gettier problems never arose for that kind of self (If I'm remembering the problems correctly) since a omniscient being (at least on the normal idea) never knows things by accident but rather knows everything all-at-once directly

Comment: No. First, God does not have to adhere to Plato's idea that knowledge=JTB. Many philosophers now do not, and in no small measure exactly because the Gettier problem proved unfixable. Second, the Gettier problem is that one may be "justified" to have a belief which happens to be true for reasons unrelated to the "justification". God needs no "justifications" for his "beliefs", and omniscience precludes the kinds of "imperfect information" scenarios that the Gettier problem exploits, so it is doubly moot.

Comment: @Conifold Ah, so my argument rested on the flawed assumption that if something is true, one cannot always have knowledge it is true?

Comment: Your argument(s) rest on the flawed assumption that limitations of human knowledge apply to God. In God's case "X is true" and "God knows X is true" are synonymous, and if a definition/description/model you use makes them incompatible so much the worse for the definition/description/model.

Comment: @Conifold You said "if a definition/description/model you use makes them incompatible so much the worse for the definition/description/model." So are you saying God cannot be proven/disproven by logic, or that a given definition/description/model does not apply to God's knowledge?

Comment: @Conifold Also, would God not knowing what a circle square would look like (essentially, can God know the impossible?) limit his knowledge? If it does, doesn't that make "X is true" and "God knows X is true" not the same?

Comment: Contradictions are just word structures that don't refer to anything that really exists. Therefore, your question amounts to asking whether God knows what something looks like that doesn't exist. Obviously, if it doesn't exist, it doesn't look like anything. These questions do little more than demonstrate the weakness of the human intellect and how easy it is for us to stumble over our own assumptions.

Comment: Although square circles are one further than simple "non-existence". There are lots of non-existent things though, which are perfectly coherent and possible. For a fairly cliché example, everyone knows what unicorns look like, and they don't exist, and there's no reason they couldn't have existed if horses evolved to grow horns. The problem with square circles is incoherence - the two definitions exclude each other. God can create anything, but also be unable to create square circles, because square circles are not part of "everything" or "anything".

Comment: Would God not knowing something still create problems if that thing wasn't a Gettier case?

Comment: There is a near consensus since Kant that (traditional monotheistic) God's existence can not be "proven" or "disproven" by logic or by empirical evidence, it is a matter of faith or lack thereof. The flip side of it is that one is free to reject God's existence without offending either reason or science. But even then omniscience is part of the conception of God, so there is no point to discussing him under models that exclude it any more than to discussing Sauron while rejecting Tolkien's universe.

Comment: God not knowing "something" is not a problem if "something" is nothing, the equation of omniscience still holds when God does not "know" X because X is nonsense. A more interesting example is foreknowledge vs. free will, see [Felt's Impossible Worlds](http://www.anthonyflood.com/feltimpossibleworlds.htm):"*But according to our principles futuribles are metaphysically monstrous: they posit the determinate outcome of a free agent’s acting while excluding the acting!  Thus, futuribles are metaphysically inconsistent fictions which cannot form an object of anyone’s knowledge, not even God’s*".

Comment: The real question is: could we be right about God not existing, for the wrong reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, Gettier illustrated a problem with the JTB definition of knowledge by identifying cases where someone "gets the right answer for the wrong reasons".  These are cases where the hypothetical person had a justified belief, and that belief was true, but are not cases where the term "knowledge" applies (basically because there is a disconnect between the person's justification and what actually happened in the real world).

Gettier cases do not say anything about whether "one cannot always have knowledge that it is true".  Indeed, the Gettier cases have little to do with the truth component of JTB (it is still the case that for all knowledge, the belief is true), instead they all relate to the justification.

Comment: Wasn't there a proposed solution to the problems by saying if your justification isn't true, it doesn't count? I thought this solution didn't work...

Comment: Actually, I think your previous edit address the question better. (The problem is with the word "cannot" in the conclusion that you drew from Gettier problems. In principle, there could be people who never ran into Gettier cases: for every justified true belief that they held, the justification itself was true. Presumably, and omniscient god would could have this feature as well.)